# zsh starts incredibly slowly

Tags: mac, zsh, oh-my-zsh

ZSH takes about a second and a half from creating a new terminal window to being ready. I'm pretty sure that the culprit is `compinit`.

I haven't been able to find good documentation on `compinit,` but it looks like it should be caching all of the necessary things in some file like `.zcompdump`.

Any tricks on speeding it up?

Comment: To be even more sure that `compinit` is the cause, [Z shell has a profiling module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524231/1886510)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`oh-my-zsh` was taking about 1.5 seconds to start up on my laptop.  [I wrote up some of the steps I took to get that down to about 0.25 seconds](http://blog.patshead.com/2011/04/improve-your-oh-my-zsh-startup-time-maybe.html).

Another kind soul [summarized the steps required to integrate my changes into your copy](http://blog.santosvelasco.com/2011/04/22/improving-oh-my-zsh-startup-time/) of oh-my-zsh.

The biggest problem is that `compinit` was being called a whole bunch of extra times instead of just one time after the fpath was completely defined.  I made those changes on my branch of `oh-my-zsh` on github.  The changes have been discussed on github and they seem to be working well for a few people.  Hopefully the changes will be merged into `oh-my-zsh` in the near future.

Comment: For future readers, I believe all these changes have now been merged upstream.

Comment: Changes may have been moved upstream, but removing Git from plugins has helped me substantially.

Comment: I have the newest version of oh-my-zsh, no changes, takes 20 seconds to start.

Comment: Removing plugins worked like charm, removed all except git.

Comment: if you want to remove git plugin for specific repo or global  https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3288#issuecomment-585201848

Answer (score 42):

While ZSH has it's own fair-share of slowdowns, if you find the terminal window blank for a few moments before you see the `Last Login:` line, you are going to need to clear your log files to see speed improvements. This is still an issue as of OSX Lion and will need to be done every several months. Lame, I know.

The command is:

```shell
sudo rm -- /private/var/log/asl/*.asl
```

Of course, [you **need** to read this article beforehand](https://osxdaily.com/2010/05/06/speed-up-a-slow-terminal-by-clearing-log-files/) and so you know exactly what is going on, because running anything that says `sudo rm` needs to be thought about. I only put this here because your use of ZSH proves your competence with the command line to start.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple solution for something that's been plaguing me for so long!

Comment: I'd recommend not using `-r` since no directories are involved and it sn't needed. Omitting it leads to less tears if someone types `sudo rm -rf / private/var/log/asl*.asl` (space before private) by mistake.

Comment: Or even more foolproof, `cd /private/var/log/asl` then `rm -f *.asl`. Also for the record, this answer saved me from a startup time that was approaching 10 seconds, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me! BTW `trash /private/var/log/asl*.asl`. `trash` will need to be installed, of course. `brew install trash`

Comment: @MikeD that should be ```trash /private/var/log/asl/*.asl``` (missed slash)

Comment: No need in `-r` and also no need in `-f`. Fixed! Now it is safer, with POSIX end of options marker `--`: `sudo rm -- /private/var/log/asl/*.asl`

Answer (score 35):

In my case, NVM was making it slow.

Original code (at .bash_profile, .zshrc loads my bash_profile)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I've changed it to:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
#[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
alias nvm="unalias nvm; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"; nvm $@"
```

Added the alias (last line), so I will only load NVM when I try to use it.
It decreased the load time from 1.5 to 0.2 seconds.

```
/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit #If you want to time yours
```

Comment: This was the case for me too. Worth mentioning that any other version manager will likely also impact startup time (jenv, pyenv, rbenv...).

Comment: This is a life saving. I was using both nvm and pyenv, both is time consuming.

Comment: this worked for me too

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Running `node` or `npm` result in `command not found` until `nvm` is invoked for the first time.

Comment: This broke `node`/`npm` for me as @varogen mentions. My [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1837322/1761444) does the above without breaking `node`/`npm`.

Answer (score 15):

My biggest improvement has come from removing items from the plugin=() section. The 'github' and 'brew' plugins are very slow to load.

I also removed [hub](http://www.github.com/defunkt/hub) which I had aliased to`git`and that sped up the prompt as well.

I've been using '/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit' to record the startup times, however `compinit` doesn't appear to make a big enough difference for me.

It'd be great to hear what others are doing to speed it up.

Comment: Removing the `github` and `brew` plugins solved my problem immediately.

Comment: `git` and `brew` plugins are quite essential to me. By removing `ruby` plugin solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Are you using the pre-installed `/bin/zsh` or another one? I ask, because
the zsh I have installed through fink starts terribly slow due its inclusion of [zsh templates](http://code.google.com/p/zsh-templates-osx/), while the vanilla starts right up.

Does running with an explicit dumpfile (`compinit -d dumpfile`) make it go faster?
The man page states that

> The  next  invocation  of compinit 
>   will  read  the dumped file instead of
>   performing a full initialization.

Comment: I am using Oh My Zsh (which I believe uses the default /bin/zsh). When I disable loading all of Oh My Zsh's plugins and whatnot, it loads up really quickly, but I think in that case `compinit` is never called. When I manually call `compinit` it takes a little while. Maybe it's just because Oh My Zsh adds so many bindings to compinit?

Answer (score 8):

Zsh on its own starts up in around 0.1 second for me, which is plenty good enough. I just noticed as I got near the 50,000 command history mark that it became more like 3 seconds to load up the first prompt.

I dunno how you guys are finding all these other reasons for slow startup, but mine was exactly what my first guess was. I did a `mv ~/.zsh_history zsh_history_backup` and bam, 3 second startup is now 0.1 second startup. Curiously, `/usr/bin/time /bin/zsh -i -c exit` fails to capture the time it takes to load in the history.

If you don't have tens of thousands of commands in your zsh history, though, then this isn't it. My `~/.zsh_history` measured 1.8MB. Its very possible to accidentally paste a large chunk of stuff as a command into a terminal, this will also bloat history up right quick (though this is something very much to avoid doing as it can obviously be extremely destructive).

Comment: This is the answer. If haven't done anything fancy (a lot of plugins and addons) with oh-my-zsh, then I guarantee it's because of the history log. The change is immediate.

Answer (score 6):

Now `oh-my-zsh` checks special git configuration option `oh-my-zsh.hide-status` before querying status. So run this on a problematic repository:

```
git config oh-my-zsh.hide-status 1
```

Comment: for me I had to disable the git plugin in `.zshrc`. I am currently facing issues with slow internet response, which made zsh slow

Answer (score 2):

I was using the theme "af-magic"

Switching to "muse" solved the issue.

Edit ~/.zshrc and modify that line:

```
#ZSH_THEME="random"
#ZSH_THEME="af-magic"
ZSH_THEME="muse"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I found changing from af-magic to something else has solved for the problem. Interestingly restoring back af-magic still works great. not sure what went on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps which I have used to optimize my shell startup speed and reducing lag in executing commands -

1. If you are using powerlevel9k, then I will recommend to immediately switch to [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k).

   > Powerlevel10k is a theme for Zsh. It emphasizes speed, flexibility and out-of-the-box experience. It is a reimplementation of the popular Powerlevel9k zsh theme. It looks exactly the same given the same configuration but renders prompt 10-100 times faster. It's optimized on every level of the stack, all the way down to using a patched version of libgit2 that can scan a repo 4 times faster than the original. It can remove Zsh startup lag even if it's not caused by a theme with features such as Instant Prompt.
2. Go to Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Command and select the option Command instead of Login Shell and paste the below command in the box nearby it.

   ```bash
   login -pfq username /usr/local/bin/zsh -il
   ```

   You wouldn't see the last login time printed when starting a new tab now. If zsh is not present in the location `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, you will need to install zsh using brew. The default zsh provided by mac is at `/usr/bin/zsh` and might be using an older version like 5.2 which can cause slow speed when used with iTerm or oh-my-zsh.
3. To make pasting in zsh fast, execute the below command in the terminal.

   ```bash
   mkdir -p $ZSH_CUSTOM/lib && touch $ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/misc.zsh
   ```
4. Point 2 should already take care of slow login times. But just for safety execute the below command

   ```bash
   mkdir -p .hushlogin
   ```
5. There are tons of plugins you might be using which are slow and creates lag. You need to point out these plugins and remove them. For this, you will need zsh profiling. Follow [this link](https://stevenvanbael.com/profiling-zsh-startup) for more details

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

I added `zmodload zsh/zprof` to start and `zprof` to end of my `~/.zshrc` file. Then I ran `exec zsh` to reload session. It turned out `is_update_available` was taking 95% of load time. I disabled auto-update by `DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"` in my `.zshrc` file. Then ran `exec zsh` and my problem was solved

Comment: Had the same problem when building `zsh` from source. Disabling auto-update did the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have really great speed improvements after clearing `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/` directory. There was many unused plugins inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your ~/.zshenv

```
skip_global_compinit=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the above answers are either:

- old, and possibly have been merged into upstream already, or
- rely on you disabling plugins that you might need later

I found a great article from 2020 by [mjclemente](https://github.com/mjclemente) that helped me to use plugins such as evalcache and zsh-nvm to speed up shell load time from ~1.65s to 0.6s without disabling any plugins: [Speeding Up My Shell (Oh My Zsh)](https://blog.mattclemente.com/2020/06/26/oh-my-zsh-slow-to-load.html)

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I stupidly had this line.

```
# pyenv
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

So it got slower and slower every time I opened a new terminal Tab.
I had 76 times that line in `.zprofile`

Comment: Ahhh this was what solved it for me! I had `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/aidanlister/.zprofile` in my .zshrc.

My .zprofile had thousands of lines of that in it. I deleted all but the first line from .zprofile, and commented out the offending line in my .zshrc, and now my terminal is fast again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Produce new dumped configuration

   ```
   rm ~/.zcompdump
   compinit
   ```

   Doing that, in my case, sped it up from 10 to 0.5 seconds. If someone knows why, please do let me know.
2. Reduce search path for function definitions. `compinit`'s hot run time increases with the size of `fpath`, according to my own benchmark:

   ```
   for x in {1..5}
   do
     for run in cold 'hot '
     do
       print -n "$run ${#fpath} \t"
       time (compinit)
     done
     fpath=($fpath $fpath)
   done

   cold 24  ( compinit; )  2,86s user 0,64s system 99% cpu 3,502 total
   hot  24  ( compinit; )  0,12s user 0,04s system 99% cpu 0,160 total
   cold 48  ( compinit; )  5,63s user 0,68s system 99% cpu 6,319 total
   hot  48  ( compinit; )  0,24s user 0,06s system 99% cpu 0,304 total
   cold 96  ( compinit; )  12,82s user 0,87s system 99% cpu 13,705 total
   hot  96  ( compinit; )  0,59s user 0,13s system 99% cpu 0,725 total
   cold 192     ( compinit; )  35,63s user 1,19s system 99% cpu 36,885 total
   hot  192     ( compinit; )  1,60s user 0,24s system 99% cpu 1,844 total
   cold 384     ( compinit; )  119,37s user 2,47s system 99% cpu 2:02,18 total
   hot  384     ( compinit; )  5,02s user 0,48s system 99% cpu 5,508 total
   ```
3. Disable important security checks using flag `-C`. That will make your setup more vulnerable and faster, according to [zshcompsys(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompsys), section "Use of compinit"

   ```
   time (compinit)
   ( compinit; )  0,19s user 0,30s system 98% cpu 0,493 total

   time (compinit -C)
   ( compinit -C; )  0,08s user 0,02s system 97% cpu 0,097 total
   ```

Answer (score 0):

*TLDR: configure lazy loading of `nvm` via the updated `.zshrc` file at the end of my answer*

---

It was `nvm` taking up nearly 88% of my load time.

One of the [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1611283/1761444) points to this but the solution breaks `node` and `npm`, making them dependent on `nvm` first being executed or you'll get these errors:

```
/Users/xxx/.nvm/nvm.sh:2833: defining function based on alias `nvm'
/Users/xxx/.nvm/nvm.sh:2833: parse error near `()'
dyld[57650]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <758FD1B7-1836-321E-A1D9-E47EC3C39702> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.5.0/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file)
```

Add `zmodload zsh/zprof` as the 1st line of your `.zshrc` file and `zprof` as the last line.

Restart your shell and you'll get something similar to this:

```
Last login: Sun Mar 31 00:15:38 on ttys000
num  calls                time                       self            name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1)    1         442.05   442.05   84.53%    254.54   254.54   48.68%  nvm_auto
 2)    2         187.51    93.75   35.86%     91.66    45.83   17.53%  nvm
 3)    1          75.70    75.70   14.48%     64.37    64.37   12.31%  nvm_ensure_version_installed
 4)   22          25.51     1.16    4.88%     21.05     0.96    4.02%  _omz_source
...
```

Nearly 90% of my loading time is took up by `nvm`!

The real way to fix this is by using the `nvm` plugin and enabling [lazy loading](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/nvm/README.md#lazy-startup), as opposed to trying to fiddle with the commands that `nvm` adds (or prompts you to add - I've forgot which one it is.

> This option will help you to **defer nvm's load until you use it to speed-up your zsh startup**. This will source nvm script only when using it, and will create a function for node, npm, npx, pnpm, yarn, and the command(s) specified by lazy-cmd option, so when you call either of them, nvm will be loaded and run with default version.

Before:

```
...
plugins=(git)
...
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

```
/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit
0.43 real         0.16 user         0.23 sys
```

After *(note the `zstyle` line added, `nvm` plugin added next to `git` & the `export NVM_DIR...` lines deleted)*:

```
...
zstyle ':omz:plugins:nvm' lazy yes
plugins=(git nvm)
...
```

```
/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit
0.14 real         0.06 user         0.06 sys
```

A ~70% decrease.